# How to display images in datatable?

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

How to display an image instead of a bool value in a cell in datatable? The datatable is associated with a datasource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put any HTML into your cells by using a custom `formatter` function. Your Column definition might look like this:

```
var myColumnSet = [
    {
        key: 'active_employee',
        label: 'Active',
        formatter: function(el, oRecord, oColumn, oData) {
            // el is the HTMLElement of the current cell
            // oRecord gives you access to other fields from the
            //    DataSource, e.g.: oRecord.getData('full_name')
            // oData is the value of the current field (active_employee)

            if (oData) {
                el.innerHTML = '<img src="/images/active.png">';
            } else {
                el.innerHTML = '<img src="/images/not-active.png">';
            }
        }
    },
    // other Columns....
];
```

Also see the [Custom Cell Formatting example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_formatting.html).

Comment: I'm running into the same issue and the above code doesn't work. Is there another way?

Comment: Sorry, I haven’t worked with YUI in several years. It’s possible this has changed. Hopefully someone more current on it can comment.

Comment: Found some info on YUI3. All I had to do was add an extra object called allowHTML: true after formatter.

Comment: @codeBarer +1 thanks a lot i was searching for that HTML option